# Auto overlay all tinyMCE modal blocks

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

how to auto overlay all block of tinyMCE modal, because i use a dynamic html content inside my modal and when the custom block change height dimension it superimposed on the next block.

[image]

Knowing that all the modal blocks are generated by default with absolute position with and "top" value coresponding to their position in modal.

Actually, I use the following script but I want to know if there is a tinyMCE function that recalculate all blocks position and that I can call it.

```
var previous = null;
$("#my_bynamic_block").closest('div').children().each(function() {
    if(previous){
        $(this).css('top', parseInt(previous.style.top.match(/\d+/)) + previous.scrollHeight + 10 );
    }
    previous = this;
});
```